# Functions with Armadillo optional parameters

Tags: c++, function, armadillo

I need to build a function with optional arguments. It seems that I should give a default values to the parameters. This approach works very well when the optional parameter type is double or integer for example. I can set the default value to 0 or NULL. But assume that the optional parameter is an Armadillo Matrix. I have no idea to define a NULL matrix. I check this code but it does not work.

```
  mat test(mat& X, mat& Y = zeros(2,2).clear()){
  if(Y.empty()){return X;}
    return X*Y;
  }
```

I wanted to set the default value of Y to a void (or empty) matrix. I can then use if command to check if Y is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `is_empty` rather than `empty` there.

The member function `reset` is [documented](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reset) to make a matrix empty. But I suspect that a default-constructed matrix is also empty.

However you have a bigger problem - you are passing the parameter Y by non-const reference, so you can't use a temporary expression as the default parameter at all . (Passing by const reference would be worse, since you'd end up with a dangling reference.) I would suggest either passing by value, or by const reference and defining a static constant for your empty matrix:

```
mat const Empty = mat();
mat test(mat const & X, mat const & Y = Empty) { ... }
```

or

```
mat test(mat X, mat Y = mat()) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank for you reply. The first code works but when I call test(x) I get an error: Y is missing without default value (It is strange). The default value is well defined. The second code does not work. Unable to parse C++ default value 'mat()' for argument Y of function test. People marked the topic as duplicated. But The solution I found requires to use Rcpp NumericMatrix and convert into Armadillo Matrix. So, Is it not possible to use default value for Armadillo parameters ?

Comment: You'll need to post more code to answer either of those. They should probably be new questions.